# How do I get my VSCode Extension's configurationDefaults to work on any file type and not on a per-language basis?

Tags: json, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I am trying to add a contributes.defaultConfiguration in the package.json that will work on all file types/languages. so far all I can find on the [Visual Studio Code Documentation for Contribution Points](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/extension-points) works on a per-language basis, an example from the site can be seen below:

```
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
        "[markdown]": {
            "editor.wordWrap": "on",
            "editor.quickSuggestions": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported as of VS Code 1.24.

An extension can set these default settings programmatically if they really need to

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as of v1.63:

```
"contributes": {
    "configurationDefaults": {
            "editor.wordWrap": "on",
            "editor.quickSuggestions": false
        }
    }
}
```

Note no language-specific grouping is required.

- see [release notes: override configuration defaults](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#configuration-defaults-overrides)